# How to do something before Gradle task's dependencies are executed?

Tags: gradle

I have the following in `build.gradle`:

```groovy
task aoeu << {
    println "**************************** during"
}

tasks.publish.dependsOn(aoeu)

tasks.publish.doFirst {
    println "************************* before"
}

tasks.publish.doLast {
    println "************************* after"
}
```

Its output is:

```
:aoeu
**************************** during
:publish
************************* before
************************* after
```

But what I really need is for the 'during' to happen between 'before' and 'after'. How can this be done? Should 'publish' simply depend on 'before'? If so, how can I guarantee that it happen before other dependencies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
task snth << {
    println "************************* before"
}

task aoeu << {
    println "**************************** during aoeu"
}
publish.dependsOn(aoeu)

task ueoa << {
    println "**************************** during ueoa"
}
publish.dependsOn(ueoa)

publish.doLast {
    println "************************* after"
}

publish.dependsOn.each { dependency ->
    if (dependency instanceof Task) {
        dependency.dependsOn(snth)
    }
}
```

will output:

```
:snth
************************* before
:aoeu
**************************** during aoeu
:ueoa
**************************** during ueoa
:publish
************************* after
```

If you want the dependency added recursively:

```
def recursivelyAddDependsOn(Task parent, Task dependsOn) {
    if (!parent.equals(dependsOn)) {
        parent.dependsOn(dependsOn)

        def tasks = parent.dependsOn.findAll { dependency ->
            dependency instanceof Task
        }
        tasks.each { task ->
            recursivelyAddDependsOn(task, dependsOn)
        }
    }
}

recursivelyAddDependsOn(publish, snth)
```

And a more functional solution is:

```
def recursivelyApplyToTaskDependencies(Task parent, Closure closure) {
    closure(parent)

    parent.dependsOn.findAll { dependency ->
        dependency instanceof Task
    }.each { task ->
        recursivelyApplyToTaskDependencies(task, closure)
    }
}

def recursivelyAddTaskDependency(Task parent, Task dependency) {
    def addTaskDependency = { p ->
        if (!p.name.equals(dependency.name)) {
            p.dependsOn(dependency)
        }
    }

    recursivelyApplyToTaskDependencies(parent, addTaskDependency)
}

recursivelyAddTaskDependency(publish, snth)
```

Comment: Now that the "`<<`" operator is deprecated, we need to use doFirst and doLast.

Answer (score 17):

<strike>As far as I know your code should work propertly but it doesn't. `doFirst` should be executed in configuration phase which is run before `doLast` (execution phase). BTW this code works fine:</strike>

As Peter Niederwiser wrote here https://stackoverflow.com/a/9204159/2069368 `doFirst` run in execution phase as first statement (before `doLast`) so your code works fine. This example will show you execution order in gradle build:

```
task publish {
    println "(1) before (run in configuration phase)" // this will run before gradle dependencies
}

task aoeu << {
    println "(2) during  (run in execution phase as last statement)"
}

tasks.publish.dependsOn(aoeu)
tasks.publish.doLast {
    println "(4) after  (run in execution phase as last statement)"
}

tasks.publish.doFirst {
    println "(3) after  (run in execution phase as FORST statement - before doLast/<<)"
}
```

It will return

```
C:\>gradle publish
(1) before (run in configuration phase)
:aoeu
(2) during  (run in execution phase as last statement)
:publish
(3) after  (run in execution phase as FORST statement - before doLast/<<)
(4) after  (run in execution phase as last statement)
```

**[UPDATE]**

Here http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/task-run-order-lt-lt-syntax-doLast-doFirst-etc-td3337481.html is great question with great example which shows execution order.

Read [this article](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_lifecycle.html) about gradle lifecycle, it will help you understand it.

**[UPDATE]**
If you want to run task `aoeu` in `publish` execution phase you can call `aoeu.execute` in `publish.doFirst`. But as far as I know it shouldn't be done in that way.

```
task publish {
}

task aoeu << {
    println "(2) during  (run in execution phase as last statement)"
}

tasks.publish.doLast {
    println "(3) after  (run in execution phase as last statement)"
}

tasks.publish.doFirst {
    println "(1) after  (run in execution phase as FORST statement - before doLast/<<)"
    aoeu.execute()
}
```

will return

```
C:\>gradle publish
:publish
(1) after  (run in execution phase as FORST statement - before doLast/<<)
(2) during  (run in execution phase as last statement)
(3) after  (run in execution phase as last statement)
```

As I see you want to run `aoeu` in the middle of `publish` task. I think that **the best way** to do it will be to divide `publish` task into two separate tasks and use `depends`, `mustRunAfter` to control execution order. Look at this example:

```
task publishInit << {
    println '(1)'
}

task aoeu << {
    println '(2)'
}

task publish << {
    println '(3)'
}

publish.dependsOn publishInit
publish.dependsOn aoeu
aoeu.mustRunAfter publishInit
```

It will return

```
C:\>gradle publish
:publishInit
(1)
:aoeu
(2)
:publish
(3)
```

Comment: So `before` can be put in the `publish` configuration. I'd like to minimize the time between `before` and `during`. Is there an alternative that would allow `before` to happen before `during` in the execution phase?

Comment: I edited my answer. But remember that calling `execute()` is wrong. As I remember it will be removed in gradle 2.0 api (but I'm not sure). Why you can't just use dependencies? It's strange that you want to call task in a middle of another. Try to refactor your build. If you want to call it in a middle of another just devide another task into two separate tasks.

Comment: Quote from the mailing list article: "Each task has a sequence of actions, which are run in the order specified when the task executes. ... The doFirst() method configures the task to add an action at the start of the sequence. The doLast() and << methods configure the task to add an action at the end of the sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Ordering tasks is headache, and `<<` is deprecated syntax.

I ended up to weave tasks as below.

```
task publish {
    println "here we go"
}

task task1 {
    println "first"
}

task task2 {
    println "second"
}

task task3 {
    println "third"
}

// task execution order. this executes bottom to top order.
publish.dependsOn task3
task3.dependsOn task2
task2.dependsOn task1
```

The `publish` task result is as below;

```
here we go
first
second
third
```